# MySQL select the last two inserted IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select the last two inserted IDs?

Here I explain how I could use these. This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (FIELD1, FIELD2, FK_TABLE2, FIELD6) 
(SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2
,(SELECT MAX(PK_Table2)
    FROM Table2
    )
,(FIELD4 + FIELD5) FROM Table1 WHERE FIELD3 = (
    (SELECT MAX(PK_Table2)
        FROM Table2) - 1
    ))
```

This should almost duplicate all records linked to the last but one record of table2, for the last record of table2.

This works right now, but only because I had not deleted a record yet.

If I delete the last record from table2 and insert another one, my generator will generate a new PK that is not the last+1.

eg: Last two IDs are: 18-19. I Delete 19 and insert another one. Now the last two IDs are 18-20. 
 So `Max(PK_Table2)` will be 20 and  `Max(PK_Table2)-1` will be 19, but I need it to be 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to steps:

1. Get the max ID
2. Get the max ID less then that

This would be:

```
WHERE FIELD3 = 
(
  SELECT MAX(PK_Table2) FROM Table2
  WHERE PK_Table2 < (SELECT MAX(PK_Table2) FROM Table2)
)
```

Another approch: Get the last two, then get the second last one.

```
WHERE FIELD3 = 
(
  SELECT PK_Table2
  FROM (SELECT PK_Table2 FROM Table2 ORDER BY PK_Table2 DESC LIMIT 2) x
  ORDER BY PK_Table2 LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Nice and simple!  Don't know why i didn't think about it.. Thanks